# How to fix this is incompatible with sql_mode = only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Good morning, maybe anyone can help, I d go tell it moved his db + web hosting from A to B, hosting web + db is in hosting A smoothly without control, I moved on to hosting B and login problem occurs, I'm trying to remove the group by her but is so random  "contents This coincidence, the web is not my artificial, so a little confused which should be corrected, thanks for the response.

[image: MySQL & Code]

[image: Ouput & Error]

Comment: Please paste your code instead of link a image here.

Comment: A [manual page on grouping correctly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)